# Stack different sized images keeping their size

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Keeping it short, I'm trying to accomplish the way https://artsy.net/browse/artworks? stacks their thumbs.

I've going crazy trying different things with bootstrap 3. But I'm starting to think that this has to be done with JS (??).

My first choice is to use a pre made jQuery plugin, but haven't found any.

Maybe I'm going blind now after many tries. I'm not asking for the exact solution, I just need some pointers as to what to look into or search for.

Comment: **Warning**: link to artsy is a little NSFW

Comment: Sorry, not following you.

Comment: Well if you scroll down there's a topless woman, which is not exactly something you would want to accidentally browse to if you were at work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with a search for "Bootstrap Thumbnail Grid".

To get you started, `.thumbnail > img` will cause the image to take up 100% of it's placeholder.
If you put the thumbnails inside of responsive columns with the same width, they should line up:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" alt="..." />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
         <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150" alt="..." />
        </a>
    </div>
    <!-- More columns -->
</div>
```

### [Working demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/yau93/)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, I have somehow tried something similar and just tweaked the demo to a more realistic example and I get the mess I'm trying to avoid.
http://jsfiddle.net/yau93/3/embedded/result/

Comment: I have found the path to follow to get to the result i need, not there yet, but this has to do with masonry: http://masonry.desandro.com/

I'm getting the images stacked like intended, now, since I'm dinamically loading images I need to dig into 'imageloaded' plugin: http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/